# Updating from Spring 3.0.5 to Spring 3.1.2 does not include aspectjrt as a dependency

Tags: spring, spring-security, aspectj

I am updating from Spring 3.0.5 to Spring 3.1.2 and while updating spring security core is also updated to 3.1.2 which in turn has dependency on aspectjrt (mentioned in its pom) but after updating to 3.1.2 if i generate dependency tree using

```
dependency:tree
```

it does not list aspectjrt in the tree but if i generate the same tree using version 3.0.5 aspectjrt is listed in the dependency tree.

Also, as previously mentioned I have already verified that aspectjrt dependency exists in both poms (version 3.0.5 & 3.1.2).

Since aspectjrt in not listed as a dependency my code is not compiled as it requires classes from aspectjrt.

If i explicitly inlude aspectjrt dependency in my pom my code compiles successfully.

Does anybody have any idea why this issue is occuring after updating to 3.1.2? Why aspectjrt is not inluded as a dependency after updating to 3.1.2

Is there any workaround for this or i will have to work by including aspectjrt as explict dependency in my pom.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved the issue. This is the expected behavior as spring security core 3.0.5 aspectjrt is not optional but in spring securoty core 3.1.2 they have marked aspectjrt as optional.

So,if you are using some piece of aspectjrt in your code you will have to include aspectjrt dependency in your pom.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

AspectJ is declared as [optional dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) in spring POM. Which means that AspectJ is required to build Spring JAR but is not required to build your project when you include Spring as dependency. If you need AspectJ functionality, include it in your POM.

Comment: Its optional in both the versions but with 3.0.5 i didn't have to include it in my pom explicitly but with 3.1.2 i have to do it. why so? Is this some bug or some intentional change?

Comment: it is possible that you have got this dependency from some other component, can you build dependency tree with 3.0.5 and check which library brings it to you?

Comment: If you have read the question carefully I have already done that and its obvious that this dependency is coming from spring. Between, i have not made any changes to the project to the project other than changing the version.

Comment: i did the same with 3.0.5.RELEASE version and i don't have aspectj in dependency tree, so please specify which library exactly is parent for aspectj

Comment: its spring security core from which aspectjrt is coming

Comment: it happened in 3.1.0, when they started using gradle for builds. this is the first version that has aspectj libraries optional